# Rails throwing error: ActionView::Template::Error (Association named 'report_type' was not found on Article; perhaps you misspelled it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
    `ActionView::Template::Error (Association named 'report_type' was not found on Article; perhaps you misspelled it?):
        37:             <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        38:               <div class="reportPage carousel-caption">
        39:               <p class="para-heading bg-circular color-white">
        40:                 <%unless @reports.present? %>
        41:                   <%= 'Statistical' %>
        42:                     <%else%>
        43:                       <%= 'Syndicate' %>



     app/views/reports/index.html.erb:40:in `_app_views_reports_index_html_erb___75771321459162625_96601780'
  app/controllers/reports_controller.rb:12:in `index'
```

I am getting this error on production, on local instance with the same data also I am not getting this error. Tried many things, not getting what's wrong.

## Article.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
       extend FriendlyId
       friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :slugged
       mount_uploader :article_image, ArticleImageUploader
       belongs_to :author
```

## ReportType.rb

```
class ReportType < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :report_type_image, ReportTypeImageUploader
  has_many :reports
  has_many :statistical_reports
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
```

Any help or suggestions on this, please.

Comment: Hope you have executed following command:
`rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: try to reset your database and try again

Comment: @Vishal- Thanks for reply, yes. It is my live website. It was done long back.

Comment: @puneet18 - reset means, delete all the data

Comment: reset means drop database, create again and run migrations

Comment: @puneet18- Too risky, as my website is live. This is the only solution?

Comment: Can you please add the code from ReportsController#index action

Comment: @DeepakMahakale - There is lot of code in my model, which is called from controller method, let me check if I can paste it here